# In Unity 2D editor, my UI text is not changing even though I told it to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a 2D platformer game on Unity Editor. However, I've got stuck when it comes to point-scoring in the game. There is a coin / resource object, and whenever the Player touches it my UI text is supposed to change, however it does not. Here are the relevant parts of the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public Text CountText;
    private int count;

#Some irrelevant code...

void Start ()
    {
        myrigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        count = 0;
        SetCountText();
    }


#Some irrelevant code...

# Death or Win 
    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.tag == "Saw")
        {
            Lose ();
        }
        if(col.tag == "Death")
        {
            Lose ();
        }
        if(col.tag == "Portal")
        {
            Finish ();
        }

    }
    
# Resource Gathering

    void onTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.tag == "isgem")
        {
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText();
            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    
    void SetCountText()
    {
    CountText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
    }
}
```

Tell me if you want the whole script. Thanks!

Comment: And how have you proved the trigger is working

Comment: As BugFinder pointed out, the problem may come from the trigger detection. I don't you your setup, but even if it was correct, the expected function name is `OnTriggerEnter2D` not `onTriggerEnter2D`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 2 onTriggerEnter2D methods?

You have to merge it:

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.tag == "Saw" || col.tag == "Death")
        {
            Lose ();
        }
        else if(col.tag == "Portal")
        {
            Finish ();
        }
        else if(col.tag == "isgem")
        {
            count++;
            SetCountText();
            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```